# Repeat characters based on a number

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm supposed to convert a certain integer value to an asterisk for the exact value of that integer.

Example: Given value = 10, I have to have 10 asterisk `**********`.

Is it possible by using the `REPLACE` function?

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: oracle sql developer

Comment: [`RPAD`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm) should help `SELECT RPAD('',5,'*') from dual;`

Comment: you can do this with a loop

Comment: @ughai it display a null value

Comment: @DurgpalSingh how so?

Comment: try this `SELECT LTRIM(RPAD(' ',6,'*')) from dual` forgot to add a space. this needs one extra value number than the `*` created. or better yet checkout @Nandu answer

Answer (score 4):

This should help you..

```
SELECT RPAD('*',10,'*') from dual;
```